# How to delete a specific rows in mySQL in a page, within a php function

Tags: php, database

I have a headache on how to delete a specific rows in my database from a function in a page. This is where I am stuck : I know I must use the specific ID from a row, so I put my $id in a while loop, and here I am stuck. Because I don't know how to retrieve that ID from a specific row. IN each row though, there's a "submit" button to delete it. Someone can help me out??

In my other page when I call these 2 functions :

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once('connect.php');
$object = new User;
if(isset($_POST['supprimer'])) {
    $object->supprimer($id);
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/layout.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $object->showConcessionnaire(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
public function showConcessionnaire(){
            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `phplogin`.`users` WHERE type='Concessionnaire'");
            $st->execute();
            echo '<form action="supprConc.php" method="post">
            <table class="tableCredit">
                <tr class="">
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Nom d\'utilisateur</th>
                    <th>Mot de pass</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>Cr&eacute;&eacute; par</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                ';
            while($r = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $id = $r['ID'];
                echo '<tr class="lightGray">
                    <td>'.$r['Date'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$r['username'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$r['password'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$r['E-mail'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$r['Creer par'].'</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="supprimer" value="X" class="logout"></td>
                    </tr>';
            }
            echo '</table></form>';
        }


    public function supprimer($id){
            $st = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `phplogin`.`users` WHERE `users`.`id` = '$id'");
            $st->execute();
        }
```

Comment: you need to give different values to your submit button which your code does not seem to be doing.

Comment: Also, I am not sure how you are calling supprimer($id) function since the only reference to this function seems to be the name of your submit button which obviously will not work.

Comment: Sidenote: I noticed you have a space in your `Creer par` column. If you haven't taken into account that columns (which have a space) need to be wrapped using backticks upon previous queries, then look into that. It won't fix your problem, am just saying. *Plus*, hyphens should also be changed to underscores `E-mail`. SQL may go haywire in thinking you want to perform a mathematical equation.

Comment: Sidenote number deux: Storing passwords in plain text, is playing with fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to insert a hidden input containing the ID of the row.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rowID" value="$id" />
```

Then when calling your function...

```
$object->supprimer($_POST['rowID']);
```

**!!** Make sure you escape your string to avoid SQL Injection!

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="supprimer" value="X" class="logout"></td>
```

to this:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="supprimer" value=".$id." class="logout"></td>
```

and then change your function call to:

```
$object = new User;
if(isset($_POST['supprimer'])) {
    $id = $_POST['supprimer'];
    $object->supprimer($id);
}
```

This is not entirely secure solution but more like a proof of concept to demonstrate the approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden input field with your id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'">
```

of course this is on your `echo` and you should move form to your `<td>`

Comment: how will it tie to the specific rows that the OP wants to delete ?